# CSS footer positioning

Tags: html, css

Problem is that the footer's text is left aligned on this page but not on any others using identical code. I went step by step commenting out each section and it is the map img that is causing this issue. I can solve this by setting the footer to clear right but that seems to completely mess up the height of the footer. I have included a couple of screen prints to help demonstrate what I mean. [image: normal]

[image]

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(..//Images/backgroundPic.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: 5px;
}
h1,
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  background-color: #F1EBEB;
}
/* Header */

#top {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(../images/tutorteam.png);
  height: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#top img {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#details {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
}
#details p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 3px;
}
div.tablerow {
  display: table-row
}
div.tablerow p:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
#logo {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#back {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#main {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
#tableContainer {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  font-size: 0.25em;
}
#footer {
  display: table-row;
}
#tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#dubaiMap {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  top: -200px;
}
#signUp {
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 90px;
}
#submit {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 420px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
textarea {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
  right: 175px;
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  font-size: 14px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sign Up</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <section id="top">
      <a href="../index.html">
        <img id="back" src="../images/back.png" height="40px">
      </a>
      <img id="logo" src="../images/tutorTeamLogo.png" height="40px">
    </section>


    <section id="main">
      <p>Are you a tutor or customer? please select the relevant option.</p>

      <form>
        <select name="user">
          <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
          <option value="Tutor">Tutor</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <form action="tutorSignUp.php" method="POST">

        <p>Please complete to sign up.</p>
        <section id="details">
          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>First name:</p>
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Last name:</p>
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="lastName" value="">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Address:</p>
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="address" value="">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>city:</p>
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="city" value="">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Zip:</p>
            <p>
              <input type="text" name="zip" value="">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tablerow">
            <p>Telephone:</p>
            <p>
              <input type="tel" name="telephone" value="">
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <img src="../Images/dubaiZones.png" id="dubaiMap">


        <p>Tutoring level</p>
        <select name="level">
          <option value="Pre School">Pre School</option>
          <option value="Primary School">Primary</option>
          <option value="GCSE">GCSE</option>
          <option value="A level">A Level</option>
          <option value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</option>
          <option value="Post Graduate">Post Graduate</option>
        </select>

        <p>Subject specialism(s)</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="English">English
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Maths">Maths
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Physics">Physics
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Chemistry">Chemistry
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Biology">Biology
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="History">History
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Geography">Geography
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Religious Studies">R.E.
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="French">French
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="German">German
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Spanish">Spanish
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Computing">Computing
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Business">Business
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Economics">Economics
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="Classics">Classics
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea id="textArea" name="comments" rows="10" cols="48">Additional Information...</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="submit">
      </form>

    </section>

    <footer>
      <table id="tableContainer">
        <tr id="footer">
          <td id="tableCell">Website design and coding provided by Technology in Learning 2016 Copyright Technology in Learning
            <img id="til" src="../Images/company.png" height="12" width="12">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you want align footer text in right hand side?

Comment: I can't really see any CSS for the footer or its image specifically. Try setting the footer `img` `max-height` to the footer height you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't undestand the need of using a table to display a single line of text.
You juste need to use a paragraph with `text-align: center;`

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
      <p class="text-center">Website design and coding provided by Technology in Learning 2016 Copyright Technology in Learning
        <img id="til" src="../Images/company.png" height="12" width="12">
  </p>
</footer>
```

Plus I think your issue is du to the use of the table. I believe by default table cell align text on the left, and I didn't see any CSS rule to change that in your code.